# How Added dynamic data to phrasemap?

Tags: dasha

In my Dasha.ai code, I want to send dynamic variables to phrasemap.json. How can I send dynamic data to phrasemap if possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To dynamic phrase you should will do:
In file "main.dsl" in context section create new variable (as example - "your_variable_phrase")

```
        context
    {
        input your_variable_phrase: string;
    }
```

and then Dasha will say variable phrases for 2 ways:

First.
Use command "sayText" - to say something without phrasemap file.
In section "do"
`#sayText($your_variable_phrase)`

Second. Use phrasemap.
In the main.dsl in section "do"

```
    #say("greeting",
    {
        your_variable_phrase: $your_variable_phrase
    }
    );
```

In phrasemap file:

```
 "greeting": {
    "first": [
      {
        "text": "Hello "},
      { "id": "your_variable_phrase", "type": "dynamic" }
    ],
```